# Can a Rails application template include generator parameters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I start a new Rails application, I often use certain parameters to `rails new` like `--skip-spring` or `--skip-turbolinks`.

I understand I can put these in `~/.railsrc`, but when using multiple dev computers, it can be a bit tedious to keep railsrc files in sync across all of them.

Can I use [application templates](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/rails_application_templates.html) to add these parameters to the generator? That would be great, because application templates can be referenced by a url and downloaded on the fly.

(Also I know I can use templates to make changes *after* the application is created, so I can remove spring or turbolinks or whatever, but it would be much nicer to never generate the app that way.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question after looking into how this works, I think the short answer is that it's not possible to add generator parameters from an application template to `rails new` itself. The reason is that the template code only runs when the application is already generated.