# Adding switches to rails application templates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, developer-tools

Rails [application templates](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/rails_application_templates.html) are a great way to take care of tedious tasks when bootstrapping a new rails app.

Is it possible to add switches to the `rails` command via a template?

For example, if I'd like to disable `spring` and I have some application template, `~/template.rb` I can disable spring like so:

```
rails new some_app --skip-spring -m ~/template.rb
```

Is it possible to put the `--skip-spring` in `template.rb`?

I know I can add these switches to my `~/.railsrc` file, but I'm curious if it's possible with templates.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can a Rails application template include generator parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39400598/can-a-rails-application-template-include-generator-parameters)